# Is there a way to deploy a custom .aspx page in the Reporting Services Pages folder?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to deploy a custom page to the
`..\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages`

folder. 
But it seems that all requests except to the `ReportViewer.aspx` page are redirected to a directory browse.

Is there a way to register a custom page?

Comment: I think you'll have an uphill battle without IIS. (SSRS doesn't use IIS, it has its own handler that works with http.sys to reduce the profile of an SSRS server.)

Comment: Indeed it's a battle. But still it would be far more easier for me if  I had the means of deploying a simple custom aspx page rather than standing up a completely new Web Application on IIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply [replacing the OOB ReportViewer.aspx file with a custom one](https://github.com/MagnusJohansson/CustomSSRSReportViewer).

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, but I think the biggest hurdle is sorting out the Report Server vs. Everything Else configuration in IIS. If you haven't already, look into your configuration options with SSRS.

[Configuring Reporting Services URL Reservations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx#URLReservations)

[URLs in Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630431.aspx)

Comment: IIS isn't used by SSRS 2008 and 2008R2 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630409.aspx . Doesn't change your answer much, though.

Comment: This really is related to entry points to the Report Manager or Report Server. It doesn't seem to be on a page level.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found, and its pretty ugly, the only way is to register your own handler(s) that overrides ReportViewerWebControl.axd. You can then read the request stream and make various changes as you need. Its not a nice solution and not highly supportable moving forwards with potential updates etc.

As an example I recently had the need to embed calls to ReportViewer.aspx in an application but support cross domain scripting, which was straight forward enough until you requested reports with date parameters and the calendar picker, which uses iframes etc for IE support. I managed to get round this with the handler approach.